# How to aim a projectile affected by wind for an Artificial Intelligence in 3D world?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm trying to make a tank game where the player must destroy the enemy tank piloted by AI. As AI has to be able to attack the player's tank. Both shots are parabolic affected by air. So far I have been able to calculate the power and minimum tilt angle to hit the shot without the projectile is affected by the wind.

```
        var Dx = target.position.x - transform.position.x;
        var Dy = target.position.y - transform.position.y;            
        var P1 = Mathf.Sqrt(9.81f * (Dy + Mathf.Sqrt(Dx * Dx + Dy * Dy)));
        var InclinationAngle = Mathf.Atan((Dy + Mathf.Sqrt(Dx * Dx + Dy * Dy)) / Dx) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;        

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(-InclinationAngle,0, 0));
        var fz = transform.forward.normalized * P1;  
        rig.AddForce(fz, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

The problem is when the projectile is affected by wind. The wind can be in one of four directions, forward, back, right or left. I have tried several approaches, but I have not got a good shot. How can the AI aim considering the starting position, target position and the strength and direction of the wind?

Comment: What are the several approaches you have tried?

Comment: it couldn't be easier.  the displacement is just wind speed times time in air.  but this question has absolutely no relationship to this site - perhaps try Physics, GameDev or the like.  this site is ONLY FOR questions about code problems.

Comment: I tried calculating the necessary strength in the upwind "var = P2 Mathf.Sqrt (Mathf.Abs (wind.force.x) * (Dx + Mathf.Sqrt (Dz Dz + Dx * * Dx)));" but practically'm guessing.

Comment: the problem is you can not know how long the projectile will fly without throwing and affected by the wind.

Comment: you need to treat the wind as a vector, instead of a constant. that will help you calculate the position it will land in.

Comment: Yes, you give me a great idea, maybe there are a parametric function for a projectile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:
Once calculated the initial rate and the minimum angle of inclination to make the trip

```
        var Dx = target.position.x - transform.position.x;
        var Dy = target.position.y - transform.position.y;
        var Vmin = Mathf.Sqrt(9.81f * (Dy + Mathf.Sqrt(Dx * Dx + Dy * Dy)));
        var InclinationAngle = Mathf.Atan((Dy + Mathf.Sqrt(Dx * Dx + Dy * Dy)) / Dx) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
```

must be added opposite to the wind force by the time of flight of the projectile divided by 2 because wee just need the half of the time because there is where the two forces are equals.

```
        var t = Dx/(Vmin * Mathf.Cos(InclinationAngle*Mathf.Deg2Rad));
        var fyx = transform.forward.normalized * P1;
        var fxz = wind.force*-t/2;

        rig.AddForce((fyx+fxz), ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Comment: Why divided exactly by 4??

Comment: I fix the posted answer